# How to create and import image into openstack?

Tags: image, openstack

I downloaded the image `precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img` from http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ , then I tried to import it into openstack using:

```
glance -v add name="ubuntu1204" is_public=true container_format=ovf disk_format=qcow2 < precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
```

The import seems OK but when I launched it I encountered error.

Where did I do wrong and what's the right procedure of creating and importing image into openstack?

Comment: What error do you get?